# How do you package a VSTO Word addin for deployment (to Office 32 bit) using WIX?

Tags: ms-word, wix, vsto, add-in, setup-deployment

I developed a `VSTO` `Word` `add in` in VS 2017 Pro.  Works fine, ready to deploy. However, I cannot find a working procedure for packaging my `VSTO` `Word` `add in` for use on machines other than my development machine. For any particular machine , I need to deploy it once and have it available for any user who may login using their account.

First came across [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2017#Obtain), but it involves using InstallShield Limited Edition which, apparently is no longer available for VS 2017.

Tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ff937654(v=msdn.10)) but it a few of its steps seem to be missing parts or say "do x" without explaining how.

Tried 'InnoSetup' and the 'bovendor/VstoAddinInstaller', but following the 'bovendor' procedure results in the 'Innosetup' compiler throwing an error (a bovender-dictated stanza is missing a required element). Can't get a response from bovendor.

Searched `Microsoft` docs and just can't find a procedure. Can anyone provide the procedure for packaging a VSTO Word add in for deployment?

**Update**
Successfully packaged and deployed my add-in using the WiX tool set. See my answer below

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Update (11/26/2019): If your setup uses 64-bit Office, see [How do you package a VSTO Word addin for deployment to a 64-bit Windows 10 machine running Microsoft Office 64 bit using WIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58629128/how-do-you-package-a-vsto-word-addin-for-deployment-to-a-64-bit-windows-10-machi)

Successfully packaged and deployed my `add-in` using the `WiX` tool set

Credit: I learned most of this using [Pieter van der Westhuizen's example](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/11/13/wix-installation-vsto-office-addin/) on the [Add-in Express Blog](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/).

I used `Visual Studio Pro 2017`, `.NET 4.6.1`, and `C#` on my development machine (64-bit) to implement my `VSTO` `Word` add-in.

My requirement is to deploy the `add-in` once to a 64-bit production machine (i.e., a Citrix virtual desktop master image) so it's available to any user who logs onto the production machine (i.e., logs on to a virtual desktop based on the master image). The 32-bit version of Word 2013 is installed on the master image.

As I understand it, this means the 'add-in' has to be installed under 'C:\Program Files (x86)' for two reasons:

1. So all users have access to the add-in, and
2. Under (x86) because it's the 32-bit version of Word).

Also, because all users need to access the `add-in`, the required `VSTO` registry key settings go under the root `HKLM` (and not `HKCU`). Essentially, this 'all users' setup is the opposite of the 'one user' `Click-Once` setup. Apropos of nothing, I'm in an enclave that is not connected to the Internet. So, all software I use is downloaded elsewhere, and then carried into the enclave and installed locally.

The release files for my `VSTO` word add-in (i.e, in `C:\....\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\FooAddIn\FooAddIn\bin\Release`) are:

- FooAddIn.dll
- FooAddIn.dll.manifest
- FooAddIn.vsto
- Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities.dll

**What I did**

- Downloaded and installed 'WiX' v3.11.1 onto my development machine from http://wixtoolset.org/releases/.
- Downloaded and installed 'Wix Toolset Visual Studio 2017 Extension' onto my development machine from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobMensching.WixToolsetVisualStudio2017Extension
- Opened my `add-in` project `FooAddIn` using `VS 2017` and in `Solution Explorer`, right-mouse clicked on the top-line `Solution` node and clicked `Add -> New Project`.
- In the `Add New Project` dialog, clicked on `v3` under `WiX Toolset` and then clicked on `Setup Project for WiX v3`. I named the new project `FooAddInSetup`. Visual Studio `Solution Explorer` shows `Solution FooAddIn (2 projects)`, project `FooAddIn`, and project `FooAddInSetup`.
- Under `FooAddInSetup -> References`, added references to `C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\WixNetFxExtension.dll` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\WixUIExtension.dll` (These are needed by elements of the Product.wxs file to build the installer).
- Configured VS to also build the setup program: In VS, click on Build -> Configuration Manager. In the Configuration Manager dialog, checked the `Build` check box for FooAddInSetup.
- Created `EULA.rtf` (mine says "This is license-free software") and placed it in C:....\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\FooAddIn\FooAddInSetup
- Created a preprocessor variable for the path to the location of my `VSTO` release files: In Solution Explorer, right mouse clicked `FooAddInSetup -> Properties`. On the FooAddInSetup tab, Clicked on 'Build'. In the `General` section, clicked `Define 'Debug' preprocessor variable`. In the `Define preprocessor variables:` textbox, entered `AddinFiles=..\FooAddIn\bin\$(Configuration)\`
- Populated the boilerplate `WiX` `Product.wxs` file for my `add-in` as shown below under **Product.wxs file**
- Note: In the `wxs` file, I modified the `Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime` hyperlink in the `Condition` element - the one in Pieter's example is dead.
- I set the Solution Configuration to `Release` and built the solution.
- Copied `FooAddInSetup.msi` from `...\FooAddInSetup\bin\release` on my dev machine to my production machine (the VDI master) and ran the setup program as admin.

**Results**

1. Without regard to the registry settings I asserted in the `wxs` file, my registry keys were created in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Word\AddIns\LesCaveatAddIn`, i.e., they went into HKLM as expected, but they went into `\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.....` instead of `\Software\Microsoft....` as I coded in the `wxs` file. I assume this is because my production machine is a 64-bit machine.
2. As expected, the add-in itself was installed under c:\program files (x86)
3. Brought up Word, and the add-in was loaded as expected

**Product.wxs file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">

  <!--
  The boilerplate Product.wxs file already contains the minimum amount of elements needed to build a WiX installer. 
  If the Product element, Id attribute is set to an asterisk (*), WiX will generate a new GUID every time the setup project is compiled (I left it as-is). 
  Change the Name attribute value and Manufacturer attribute value to values of your choice.
  -->
  <Product Id="*"
           Name="FOO Add-In"
           Language="1033"
           Version="1.0.0.0"
           Manufacturer="Foo Masters"
           UpgradeCode="4b35cc09-4780-4644-a7d4-f5901f7a7e45">

    <!--Attributes shown are the minimum number needed to build the setup project.-->
    <Package InstallerVersion="200"
             Compressed="yes"
             InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />

    <!-- Verify if VSTO Office Runtime is installed -->
    <Property Id="VSTORUNTIMEREDIST">
      <RegistrySearch
        Id="VSTORuntimeRedist"
        Root="HKLM"
        Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4R"
        Name="Version"
        Type="raw" />
    </Property>

    <Condition
      Message="The Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime is not installed. 
  Please download and install from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48217.">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR VSTORUNTIMEREDIST>="10.0.30319"]]>
    </Condition>

    <!-- Verify if .NET Framework is installed -->
    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40FULL"/>
    <Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 4.0.">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK40FULL]]>
    </Condition>

    <!--I want one Cab file, so only one Media element is needed. Make sure the EmbedCab attribute value is "yes".-->
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="FooAddin.cab" EmbedCab="yes"/>

    <!--Set values for display on setup progeam UI-->
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="FOO Add-In" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
      <ComponentRef Id="Registry_FriendlyName" />
      <ComponentRef Id="Registry_Description" />
      <ComponentRef Id="Registry_Manifest" />
      <ComponentRef Id="Registry_LoadBehavior" />
    </Feature>

    <!--Specify that the WiXUI_Minimal UI should be used, i.e, the simplest UI available -->
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />

    <!--Specify the EULA file to use-->
    <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="EULA.rtf" />

  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="FooAddin" />

        <!-- Add required VSTO registry entries for 32-bit Word -->
        <!-- see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/registry-entries-for-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019-->

        <Component Id="Registry_FriendlyName">
          <RegistryValue Id="RegKey_FriendlyName" Root="HKLM"
                         Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\AddIns\FooAddin"
                         Name="FriendlyName"
                         Value="FOO Add-In"
                         Type="string" KeyPath="yes" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="Registry_Description">
          <RegistryValue Id="RegKey_Description" Root="HKLM"
                         Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\AddIns\FooAddin"
                         Name="Description"
                         Value="FOO Add-In"
                         Type="string" KeyPath="yes" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="Registry_Manifest">
          <RegistryValue Id="RegKey_Manifest" Root="HKLM"
                         Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\AddIns\FooAddin"
                         Name="Manifest" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]FooAddin.vsto|vstolocal"
                         Type="string" KeyPath="yes" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="Registry_LoadBehavior">
          <RegistryValue Id="RegKey_LoadBehavior" Root="HKLM"
                         Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\AddIns\FooAddin"
                         Name="LoadBehavior" Value="3"
                         Type="integer" KeyPath="yes" />
        </Component>

      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>

    <!-- Add refs to the components of the VSTO-->

    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">

      <Component Id="MSOfficeToolsCommon_dll_Component">
        <File Id="MSOfficeToolsCommon_dll" KeyPath="yes"
          Name="Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities.dll"
          Source="$(var.AddinFiles)"></File>
      </Component>

      <Component Id="FooAddin_dll_Component" >
        <File Id="FooAddin_dll" KeyPath="yes"
              Name="FooAddin.dll"
              Source="$(var.AddinFiles)" />
      </Component>

      <Component Id="FooAddin_vsto_Component">
        <File Id="FooAddin_vsto" KeyPath="yes"
          Name="FooAddin.vsto"
          Source="$(var.AddinFiles)"></File>
      </Component>

      <Component Id="FooAddin_dll_manifest_Component">
        <File Id="FooAddin_dll_manifest" KeyPath="yes"
          Name="FooAddin.dll.manifest"
          Source="$(var.AddinFiles)"></File>
      </Component>

    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you for sharing your knowledge and providing us a nice step-by-step write-up.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use the [Click-Once deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment?view=vs-2019) within Visual Studio. You can deploy it to a network path so other users will be able to install it.

### First you want to create a non-expiring certificate for Visual Studio projects

Type `Developer Command` in the Start Menu search and right click and select <kbd>Run as administrator</kbd>

[image: Start Menu]

Paste the following commands in the command prompt for [MakeCert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [pvk2pfx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550672%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
MakeCert /n "CN=Your New Cert" /r /h 0 /eku "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13" /e "01/01/2100" /sv MyNewCert.pvk MyNewCert.cer 
pvk2pfx -pvk MyNewCert.pvk -spc MyNewCert.cer -pfx MyNewCert.pfx
```

**Note:**

- The date format is the US standard `MM/DD/YYYY`
- The `-f` parameter can be used at the end of the pvk2pfx line for overwriting an existing file
- You'll get prompted to create a password (this is optional)

[image: cmd prompt]

After the password prompt, you'll need to run the second command line by just pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

[image: cmd prompt2]

### Now you can select the same certificate for multiple Visual Studio projects

In the Visual Studio project properties, select <kbd>Signing*</kbd> click on <kbd>Select from File…</kbd>.
Navigate to the same path from the command prompt and select the certificate file (*.pfx)

[image: Visual Studio Signing]

### Publish the project

Then go to the **Publish** tab in the project properties and click <kbd>Publish Now</kbd>. It will create a executable file in the published location. Then you just need to send a link to the `.exe` file to your end-users.

[image: publish]

Comment: Thank-you for the great details, but Click-Once won't do it for me because as I understand it, Click-Once is used when you want an an individual user to install an add-in on a machine for just their login.  I need to install it such that the VSTO add-in is available to all users who might log into the machine. [See **Register VSTO Add-ins for the current user vs. all users** at this location for implementation details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/registry-entries-for-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019). I'm looking at WIX right now. I think maybe it will do it.

Comment: Yes, you're right Click-Once is per user. I'll be interested in seeing the solution you get to install for all users on a machine. If it helps you, here are a bunch of my VSTO projects on [GitHub](https://github.com/Excel-projects)

Comment: see my answer below